# Error: Cannot add foreign key constraint on CREATE TABLE

Tags: mysql, sql, key

When i run this, i get the error : Cannot add foreign key constraint 
Can anyone help me? thanks

```
CREATE SCHEMA `Rubik's_Cubes`;
USE `Rubik's_Cubes`;

/*Tabella Collezionista*/
CREATE TABLE Collezionista(
    id INTEGER auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
    nome TEXT NOT NULL,
    cognome TEXT NOT NULL,
    telefono INTEGER NOT NULL,
    ranking INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    id_ogg_pref INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY (id_ogg_pref) REFERENCES Oggetto(id)
        ON DELETE SET NULL
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

/*Tabella Possiede*/
CREATE TABLE Possiede(
    id_collezionatore INTEGER NOT NULL,
    id_oggetto INTEGER NOT NULL,
    tempo_sol DOUBLE DEFAULT NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY (id_collezionatore) REFERENCES Collezionista(id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION,

    FOREIGN KEY (id_oggetto) REFERENCES Oggetto(id)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);

/*Tabella Oggetto*/
CREATE TABLE Oggetto(
    id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    nome TEXT NOT NULL,
    id_tipo INTEGER NOT NULL,
    id_tipo2 INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
    valore DOUBLE NOT NULL,
    descrizione TEXT NOT NULL,
    detentore_record INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
    tempo_record DOUBLE DEFAULT NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY (id_tipo) REFERENCES Tipologia(id)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE CASCADE,

    FOREIGN KEY (id_tipo2) REFERENCES Tipologia(id)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE CASCADE,

    FOREIGN KEY (detentore_record) REFERENCES Collezionista(id)
        ON DELETE SET NULL
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

/*Tabella Tipologia*/
CREATE TABLE Tipologia(
    id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    nome TEXT NOT NULL,
    descrizione TEXT NOT NULL,
    provenienza TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sequence of executing the Create statements are not correct.
You try to add the constrainst related to a table which doesn't exists yet.

Example: 
Your are trying to create the ***Collezionista*** table and add foreign key contraint to table ***Oggetto***, before even creating table ***Oggetto***.
So, you need to create the reference table or Parent table first, then create the child table.

Also, tables ***Oggetto*** and ***Collezionista*** are inter dependent. You need to remove FOREIGN KEY from table ***Oggetto*** and add as alter at last.

*Pleas follow below sequence of execution:*'

```
CREATE TABLE Tipologia(
id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
nome TEXT NOT NULL,
descrizione TEXT NOT NULL,
provenienza TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Oggetto(
id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
nome TEXT NOT NULL,
id_tipo INTEGER NOT NULL,
id_tipo2 INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
valore DOUBLE NOT NULL,
descrizione TEXT NOT NULL,
detentore_record INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
tempo_record DOUBLE DEFAULT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (id_tipo) REFERENCES Tipologia(id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (id_tipo2) REFERENCES Tipologia(id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
);
```

CREATE TABLE Collezionista(
    id INTEGER auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
    nome TEXT NOT NULL,
    cognome TEXT NOT NULL,
    telefono INTEGER NOT NULL,
    ranking INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    id_ogg_pref INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (id_ogg_pref) REFERENCES Oggetto(id)
        ON DELETE SET NULL
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
    );

CREATE TABLE Possiede(
    id_collezionatore INTEGER NOT NULL,
    id_oggetto INTEGER NOT NULL,
    tempo_sol DOUBLE DEFAULT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (id_collezionatore) REFERENCES Collezionista(id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
    FOREIGN KEY (id_oggetto) REFERENCES Oggetto(id)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    );

ALTER TABLE Oggetto
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (detentore_record) REFERENCES Collezionista(id)
   ON DELETE SET NULL
   ON UPDATE CASCADE

Hope it helps you.

Thanks,
Abhijit Das

Answer (score 1):

You try to add a constraint related to a table which doesn't exists yet.

You should remove this on your create tables statements :

```
FOREIGN KEY (id_ogg_pref) REFERENCES Oggetto(id)
    ON DELETE SET NULL
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

then add it at the end with an `alter table` . See that example for the 1st table:

```
/*Tabella Collezionista*/
ALTER TABLE Collezionista
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (id_ogg_pref) REFERENCES Oggetto(id)
    ON DELETE SET NULL
    ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```